# The distance of two point which SDO_CLOSEST_POINTS returns is not the same as dist itself returns

Tags: oracle, spatial

When i query distance between two Geometries like this:

```
DECLARE
  dist  NUMBER;
  geoma SDO_GEOMETRY;
  geomb SDO_GEOMETRY;

BEGIN
  SDO_GEOM.SDO_CLOSEST_POINTS(sdo_geometry('POINT(10 10)', 4326),
                              sdo_geometry('POLYGON((0 0, 2 0, 2 2, 0 2, 0 0))',
                                           4326),
                              0.005,
                              NULL,
                              dist,
                              geoma,
                              geomb);
  insert into test (info, geom1, geom2) values (dist, geoma, geomb);

END;
```

It returns like this:

- info:1254057.74485897
- geom1: 10,10
- geom2: 2,2

But when i query the distance between the two points:

```
SELECT sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_geom.sdo_geometry('POINT(10 10)', 4326),
                             sdo_geom.sdo_geometry('POINT(2 2)',
                                                   4326),
                             0.0001,
                             'unit=M') distance_in_m
  from DUAL;
```

It returns :1251344.03770147

Why the distances are not the same?How it happen?
Thanks for anyone who will give me some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [`SDO_GEOMETRY` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-object-type.htm#SPATL492) gives a different way of specifying shapes. Using this, the values are the same:

```
DECLARE
  d1 NUMBER;
  d2 NUMBER;
  d3 NUMBER;
  g1 SDO_GEOMETRY := SDO_GEOMETRY(
                      2003,                              -- 2 dimensional polygon,
                      NULL,                              -- No SRID / Co-ordinate System
                      NULL,                              -- SDO_POINT,
                      SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY( 1, 1003, 3 ), -- Rectangle exterior
                      SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY( 0,0, 2,2 )     -- Corners
                     );
  g2 SDO_GEOMETRY := SDO_GEOMETRY(
                      2001,                              -- 2 dimensional point,
                      NULL,                              -- No SRID / Co-ordinate System
                      SDO_POINT_TYPE(10,10,NULL),        -- SDO_POINT,
                      NULL,                              -- Not an array
                      NULL                               -- Not an array
                     );
  g3 SDO_GEOMETRY := SDO_GEOMETRY(
                      2001,                              -- 2 dimensional point,
                      NULL,                              -- No SRID / Co-ordinate System
                      SDO_POINT_TYPE(2,2,NULL),        -- SDO_POINT,
                      NULL,                              -- Not an array
                      NULL                               -- Not an array
                     );
  ga SDO_GEOMETRY;
  gb SDO_GEOMETRY
BEGIN
  SDO_GEOM.SDO_CLOSEST_POINTS(
    geom1     => g1,
    geom2     => g2,
    tolerance => 0.005,
    unit      => NULL,
    dist      => d1,
    geoma     => ga,
    geomb     => gb
  );

  d2 := SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE( g2, g3, 0.0001, NULL );

  d3 := SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE( g1, g3, 0.0001, NULL );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( d1 || ', ' || d2 || ', ' || d3 );
END;
/
```

**Outputs**:

```
11.3137084989848, 11.3137084989848, 11.3137084989848
```

As an added bonus, the distance is now `SQRT(8*8 + 8*8)` which is the Cartesian distance from (2,2) to (10,10) and you can also use `SDO_DISTANCE` with either the polygon or the point for the same answer.

Comment: But when i change the SRID to 4326,it returns:1254057.74485897, 1251344.03770147, 1254057.74485897.I think compute between point to polygon and point to point is disffence.

Comment: @chen.wenwen The co-ordinate system (SRID) is the root cause of the problem - since leaving everything else the same and changing that one thing (from no coordinate system [`NULL`] to latitude/longitude [`4326`] ) gives the difference.